Reactjs routes are not working in Apache2
I have the following route setup in my ReactJS application:
<Route path={`${process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL}/:siteid/apply`} element= {<DriverSetup />} />

REACT_APP_PUBLIC_URL is testfiles
In development: I use the url:
https://localhost:3000/testfiles/mydriver/apply and the page pulls up as expected.
.htaccess looks like this:
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]

In production running Apache2 in a LAMP environment I use the url:
https://mytestserver.com/testfiles/mydriver/apply and the page is blank.
It appears the browser loaded the page (Status code 200 on the page get).  I'm a bit confused as the code is exactly the same.  Is there an Apache setting that I may be missing?  Where do I even begin to troubleshoot this?
You guys were quick to close this quest as the answer provided did not fix my issue.  Is there anything else I can look at?

Would love to say that it does but the question was my original question before it was abruptly closed.  I made the changes to my .htaccess file but it still does not work.
